# creating c++ dll which depends on another c++ dll

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, .so

I have the following setup.

file1.h, folder1, file1.so,
file2.h, file2.cpp

In my visual studio:
Library directory paths I give: folder1 (which contains file1.so)

Now I create a dll using file2.cpp which has the following:

file2.cpp:

```
  #include "file2.h"
  #include <file1.h>
  ,,,
  other file2 relevant code.
```

Now I create the file2.so

Finally when I call my file2.so from other programs I need to

1. keep file1.so in the same directory as file2.so
2. set the path environment variable to the same directory as file1.so and file2.so

From my empirical experiments I found that If I do not so step 2 above the file2.so file does not know where to load the file1.so when it is needed within it.

My question: is there any way to create the file2.so without explicitly doing step 2. How can I create file2.so such that it knows to search for file1.so in the same directory as it is residing in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a dll or an so?  The answer will likely be different, so please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: "_set the path environment variable_": The `PATH` environment variable has nothing to do with dynamic linking. It is not relevant.

Comment: `#include 'file2.h'` is not valid syntax. Do you mean `#include "file2.h"`?

Comment: my understanding: .so in linux context = .dll in the window context. I am developing the in linux

Comment: If you're developing ON Linux, then you want .so, not .DLL. You should update the title accordingly. Also, you're probably not using Visual Studio, maybe VS Code. You should update your question accordingly. Also, you should not include your own files with `<` ... Now, generally speaking, you put the dynamic libraries in the same directory as your application... You could set the path, but usually not needed. Or, look up how Linux finds .so files. (I only know windows off the top of my head, but Linux is probably CWD and Path)